# How do I tail top -c?

Tags: linux

I have a couple ruby scripts running on my machine and some other ruby processes. The only way I can differentiate them with top is by doing top -c (so I can see the command, otherwise everything is just 'ruby').

I want to be able to watch how many scripts are running so I can restart them if one fails.

I am thinking I can do this with `top -c -n 1 | grep "script-name"` but I can't figure out how to `tail -f` that or if that command is the best way to do it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `top` it's not the best choice here, because it's an interactive command and you can't really pipe its **whole** output (probably there is a way). One of the *fair enough* ways to do it would be using `ps`:

```
ps -e -o pid,cmd | grep "script-name"
```

If you want to periodically investigate this, you can also use `watch`:

```
watch 'ps -e -o pid,cmd | grep "script-name"'
```

In general, it's a bad practice to grep `ps` output, but I suppose in your case will work. If you only want the number of running processes that match against a pattern or you just want their PIDs, you'd better go with `pgrep`.

```
pgrep "script-name"
```